# Iteratively fill NaN values in xarray with dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have a large three-dimensional dataset (y, x, time) with significant gaps (NaN). I would like to iteratively fill the missing values with the value from the previous time.

Here is a toy example:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# 1. Generate a sample DataArray with missing values
dims = ('y', 'x', 't')
shape = (1000, 1000, 10)
coords = {d: np.arange(s) for d, s in zip(dims, shape)}
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, shape)
data = np.where(mask, np.random.rand(*shape), np.nan)
da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=dims, coords=coords)

# 2. Write and reload from disk as dask array
da.to_netcdf('_tmp.nc')
da = xr.open_dataarray('_tmp.nc', chunks={'y': 100, 'x': 100, 't': 1})

# 3. Iteratively fill gaps
for t in range(1, len(da['t'])):
    # The following doesn't work with dask arrays
    da[{'t': t}] = da[{'t': t}].fillna(da[{'t': t-1}])
```

This would work fine, except dask arrays don't support item assignment and hence the last line doesn't work. My dataset is too large to read into memory, so calling `.load()` is not an option.

Is there any way to use `.fillna()` in this way while still making use of the lazy evaluation of chunks provided through dask?

My real data is about 10000x10000x100 and contains multiple variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, this sort of operation is only partially supported in Xarray. Ideally, you could use `da.ffill()` but there are some existing problems with the implementation that may not give you the desired result (to be explicit, xarray does not currently support filling between chunks).

You may want to take a look at this GitHub issue to try out a potential workaround: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2699.

I encourage you to engage on this issue if it seems like what you're going for.

Comment: For now it seems like `da.ffill()` does indeed exactly what I need, and I can probably adapt my chunk sizes accordingly. If I run into problems I will happily get back to the GitHub issue.